# Get modules structure in Yii2 Advanced Template

Tags: module, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

In order to create a table to assing permissions I need to know the modules of my app (and controllers and acctions of each), of course I can use

```
    Yii::$app->modules
```

But it returns only loaded modules, and I want to make my permissions table in `backend` so I receive the common and `backend` modules (and it is OK) but not `frontend` ones (and this is the problem).

Other approach should be `ModuleName::getInstance();` but I need the `ID` previously and what I want is scan all the present modules in common, `backend` and `frontend`.

Any approach or suggestion are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Can you get the list of modules from config files? That way you'll know which application uses which modules.

Comment: I don't know how to get the list of modules from config files.

Comment: I've posted my answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application has access to all files, you can easily get the list of modules from other applications' configuration.

I assume you're using the "advanced" application template.

```
$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../../frontend/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../../frontend/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../../backend/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../../backend/config/main-local.php')
);

$modules = array_keys($config['modules']);
```

The paths might need some correction. Also, you can register an alias that points to your root directory and use it.

The same approach is used in your `/web/index.php` to instantiate the current application.

Comment: A simply, elegant and excelent approach, thanks a lot it works perfectly.